# Output a matrix with c++ and mex

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have a problem with my c++ code. I want to return a matrix of k-dimensions from my cpp program to Matlab.

The matrix I want to pass is stored in `all_data`, and is a matrix of size `(npoints+1) x ndims`.

I have been looking how to do that, and I have come up with:

```
    //send back points
    vector< vector <double> > indexes = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    for (int i=0; i < (npoints1+1); i++)
            for (int j=0; j < ndims1; j++)
                indexes[ i ][ j ] = all_data[ i ][ j ];
```

But it does not work, as `all_data` is a `vector<vector<double>>` variable, and matlab says:

```
error: conversion from 'double*' to non-scalar type 
'std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, 
std::allocator<std::vector<double, 
std::allocator<double> > > >' requested
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like mxGetPr is returning you a pointer to an array of doubles and you are assigning it to a vector of vectors.

This should work:

```
double* indexes = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

`mxGetPr` does not return a `vector<vector<double> >`.  It returns a `double *`.  MATLAB arrays are stored contiguously in memory, column-major.  Assuming you've created plhs[0] with the correct dimensions, then all you need to do is this:

```
double *indexes = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
for (int i=0; i < (npoints1+1); i++)
    for (int j=0; j < ndims1; j++)
        indexes[i + ndims1*j] = all_data[ i ][ j ];
```

Note the conversion of the 2 indices to a linear offset.

Comment: are you sure about indexes[i + ndims1*j] ? i'd do i * (npoints1+1) + j. But i might be wrong.

Comment: In normal C, yes, you're right.  But MATLAB, arrays are stored transposed of what we expect.  So x(2,6) is right next to x(3,6).  That's what "column-major" means.  It's a leftover from FORTRAN days.