# Returning N vectors of type int from C++ to matlab via mexfunction?

Tags: c++, matlab, vector, compiler-errors, mex

I am trying to return a vector back to matlab using the mex function. I declare a return pointer as,

```
double *retPtr = NULL;
```

Then the return code is as follows:

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(N, 1, mxREAL); 
retPtr = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
{ 
retPtr[i] = forest->predictLabel(&(testData[i*M]), M); 
}
```

The return type is a vector , but I keep on getting the error:

```
Error   1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'double'
```

I there a problem the way I declare the pointer. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards, 
Eric

Comment: If your return type is a `std::vector`, shouldn't you be declaring it as such rather than a pointer to a double?

Comment: I am not sure , how to do that, can you suggest how to do that?

Comment: Not familiar with `mxGetPr` but the compiler appears to be telling you what it returns - is that definitely from the mxGetPr line? You could take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115584/output-a-matrix-with-c-and-mex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change

```
retPtr[i] = forest->predictLabel(&(testData[i*M]), M);
```

to

```
retPtr[i] = i;
```

then it will compile and run, returning a vector to MATLAB.

Of course, you probably didn't want a vector simply counting from `0` to `N-1`.  But you will have to figure out the C++ code to get the numbers you want.  None of us have any idea what your `forest` object or `predictLabel` function are doing.

---

To actually return `N` different vectors, you can pack them in a cell array (this allows the size to vary).

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateCellMatrix(M, 1);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
{ 
    std::vector<int> results = forest->predictLabel(&(testData[i*M]), M); 
    mxArray* ithCell = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(results.size(), 1, mxREAL); 
    retPtr = mxGetPr(ithCell);
    for (int j = 0; j < results.size(); ++j)
        retPtr[j] = results[j];
    mxSetCell(plhs[0], i, ithCell);
}
```

Comment: The predictlabel is just calculating the vector, and the forest is just used to access the predictlabel function. When I return just a single integer value from predictLabel, it works all fine without any error, and I get the N outputs in matlab.

Comment: @efn: So how many outputs are you trying to return?  `N`?  `N*k`?  Each `predictLabel` call has a different number of elements?  Your vector has more than one element, so it will have to occupy more than one element in the matrix returned to MATLAB.

Comment: There are N vectors , but the number of elements vary in each vector, but I could put an upper limit on that, because I know the number of elements it won't exceed.

Comment: @efn: Well, what should the data look like when it gets back to MATLAB?  A square matrix with NaNs in the unused slots?  A cell array of vectors of varying length?  All individual vectors concatenated into a single column vector?  First put the data into a MATLAB variable by hand, then you (with our help if needed) can figure out the C++ MEX code to generate it.

Comment: @efn: The key point is that you wrote code to, as your question says, return "a" vector back to MATLAB.  But you actually have `N` vectors.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, since i was testing for a single vector first.

Comment: @efn: Do you mean that `N` is 1?

Comment: yes, for testing I just passed in a single test data, to see if I get the desired output.

Comment: Well, I suggest `plhs[0] = mxCreateCellMatrix(N, 1)` and then use `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` for each of your `N` result vectors.

Comment: how to declare plhs[0] twice. Could you give an example using the above code, that would be very useful.

Comment: @efn: Example added (but not tested)